# git diff -w produces broken patch

Tags: git, version-control, newline, patch, git-diff

Given is a git branch that introduces some relevant changes, but also introduces a lot of whitespace changes (mostly LF->CRLF) by accident. I think this is pretty common out there (but should be avoided, no question).

Now I want to create a patch for this branch, but without lines that have only whitespace changes. "Easy", I thought.

So I will create a patch with **`git diff -w <branch>`**. **However, this patch is broken** (`git-apply` complains `"patch does not apply"`), because the context for each hunk contains the whitespace changes that the branch introduced that I don't have.

`git apply --ignore-whitespace` will fix the problem, but this seems wrong. Interestingly, `git diff -R -w <branch>` produces a reverse patch that is not broken if applied with `git apply -R`, because the context is relative to my HEAD and not the HEAD in `<branch>`.

Instead, I was expecting something like a `--patch` option to `git-diff` that will output a valid patch with any combination of other valid arguments to `git-diff`. Even more radically speaking, this behavior of `git-diff` seems like a bug to me, if its output is expected to function as a patch.

**So, two questions:**

- **do you think this behaviour is a bug?**
- **are you aware of any standard way to create a "patchable" diff with `git-diff` and special options like `-w`?**

Of course the "applier" of the patch can use the `--ignore-whitespace` option, but again, this seems wrong to me, and not everyone is aware of this option.